# Trying to override pg_hba.conf in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I'm using the lastest Docker PostgreSQL 14.1 image and trying to change the file pg_hba.conf to use md5 (Dev machine):

```
# host all all all scram-sha-256
host all all all md5
```

I have a modified pg_hba.conf file locally that I'm trying to use.  In my Dockerfile I do the following:

```
RUN rm -f /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
COPY ./postgresql/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

where ./postgresql/pg_hba.conf is the modified version that allows the use of md5

When I run docker-compose build everything seems to be working as expected.

```
Step 5/7 : RUN rm -f /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
---> Using cache
---> 20e82128335a
Step 6/7 : COPY ./postgresql/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
---> Using cache
---> cc41cb9267d8
Step 7/7 : CMD ["tail", "-F", "-n0", "/etc/hosts"]
---> Using cache
---> 9cb31d31a1a3
Successfully built 9cb31d31a1a3
Successfully tagged fileshare_db:latest
```

Currently, I'm not running the database and just using the following so I can keep the container without turning on the database so I can see if the commands work:

```
CMD ["tail", "-F", "-n0", "/etc/hosts"]
# CMD ["postgres"]
```

But when I go into the container and do a cat command on pg_hba.conf it still has the old settings

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
...
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256
```

Here is part of my compose file that is specific to the postgresl

```
    db:
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.postgres
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    networks:
        - fileshare-network
    volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ../../backups/database:/var/backups

...
volumes:
    db-data:
        driver: "local"
```

**Update**
For now, I'm just copying the file manually.  I put it in /var/backups and overwrite the file in /var/lib/postgresql/data and then restart to get it to work.

The one positive is I only have to do this once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your `Dockefile`:

```
ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=md5
```

Or `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
db:
  environment:
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: md5
    PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

And you can delete these lines:

```
RUN rm -f /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
COPY ./postgresql/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: It does work unfortunately, Postgresql will not install saying that the folder data already exists.  For now, I'm just manually copying it to that location. - Thanks

Comment: Can you try to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD? I rewrote the answer.

Comment: PGDATA ENV might help you.

Comment: Perfect, that worked.  Much appreciated